# Dissmiss from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I guess it can be duplicated, but I looking everywhere and didn't find a solution for me.

So about my question. I have something like this
[open this image to see more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENEpF.png)

In my AppDelegate I have func

```
func logIn() {

    let userExist = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_key_user")
    if userExist != nil && userExist != "" {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let whereToGo = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllPostsOfUserTabBarController") as! AllPostsOfUserTabBarController
        window?.rootViewController = whereToGo
    }
}
```

If user exist it lead me to first view controller inside tab bar controller. There I have navigation button with action to logout. 
I need log out(send data to the server) and then go to my first view controller with text field and button where I can again log in.

How do I need to implement it?

Comment: Any issue faced using above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code after logout-

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think it just says which one controller should be initials, but not open it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I believe it stays in UITabBarController, because it shows print from viewWillAppear in UITabBarController

Comment: My bad. It works, it just me, dummy. I forgot to switch in func from AppDelegate. I tried to connect not only to UITabBarController but to UINavigationController and see what happened. 
Thank you for the answering.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in function of your logout button. It will throw you back to your root controller.

```
func logoutBtnClicked()
{
   DispatchQueue.main.sync()
   {
    (send your data to server)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in appdelegate

**While Login**

```
    self.window?.rootViewController = whereToGo
```

**While Logout**

```
 func setupLoginViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginVC: UIViewController? = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVCID") as? UIViewController
       let navController: UINavigationController? = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC!) as UINavigationController

        window?.rootViewController = navController
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean "Constant.StoryBoard..."?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mentioned that it is the storyboard object.

Comment: @Abhishek Jain gave an answer.

Your code works as well, but after it back to initial view controller and I push the button nothing happened. My code looks like this:
`@IBAction func transferData(_ sender: Any) {

        let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController


        myVC.textInputTB = textField.text!
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
    }`

Comment: it will works if you have use navigation controller as root viewcontroller .

Comment: I got it! Thank you.